# Java set Content-Desposition to HTTP Body

Tags: java, http, http-post, content-disposition

I am using DefaultHttpClient and MultipartEntityBuilder for sending an image but the server requires a Content-Disposition Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name" filename="image.jpg". How can I set this to the body of the HttpPostRequest? I searched for an answer for about 3 hours and couldn't make it work.

Comment: Afaik, you can't set the content-disposition anywhere but the HTTP header.

Comment: Well a friend of mine has added it in the body and it works. But he is using objective C.

Comment: Programming language is immaterial here. That's not how web browsers work.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the "body" of the message, as @ElliotFrisch points out.

You've got an [`HttpMessage`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html), so just call [`addHeader(...)`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#addHeader(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
request.addHeader("Content-Disposition",
                  "form-data; name=\"name\" filename=\"image.jpg\"");
```

Before you send it via your `DefaultHttpClient`.